# Jquery Connection to internet message

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, connection

I have a Jquery function that works perfectly if the user is connected to the internet

```
$("a[id ^= 'toggle']").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $("div [id='replypost_"+$(this).attr('id').replace('toggle_','')+"']").toggle();
});
```

This tag is what triggers it

```
<a href= '' id ='toggle_$id'><img src='design/reply.png' class='like'/><h4 class='liketext'>Send Message</h4></a>
```

My question is, if the user is not connected to the internet then when the `<a>` tag is click the page just refreshes but when the user is connected to the internet it works perfectly. Is there a way I can check if the user is connected to the internet, and alert them a message if the connection is not active?

Comment: The page may be refreshing because they can't download jQuery

Comment: If this is to be run locally - (the only reason I would imagine they'd ever be on this page with no internet connection) - then store the jquery file(s) locally too.

Comment: Yea that is what I am going to do, it is local for testing purposes!

Comment: Try html5bp's method of doing this: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L27 (line 27 and 28)